# turn off blue lines under autocorrected words, but leave autocorrect on

Tags: ios, autocorrect

When I type on my iPhone I rely a decent amount on autocorrect to figure out what I wanted, and it's almost always right. When it isn't I delete the word and retype it.

Seems like in a recent update, they've started adding blue lines underneath every word that was autocorrected. I find this extremely annoying because usually at that point it's already been autocorrected to the right thing, but it makes my brain focus on it and interrupts my flow of tapping. Even though there isn't usually any further change to be made.

What I want is to go back to the old way, where autocorrect was still on (which I love) but there weren't these blue lines (which I hate). Any way to do that?

Comment: Once you've finished your word (& it's correct, whatever the phone thinks), if the phone doesn't know it, then tapping the left-most auto-suggest space, the one with quotes round it, will add it to the list of words. It will eventually start suggesting those as auto-suggestions.